# Palma center to Coves del Drac

Tags: public-transport, spain, southeast-europe, caves, mallorca

I want to go from Palma center to the Coves del Drac via public transport. I do see routes via Google Maps but where I can find the updated costs of buses? I tried searching on one website but it doesn't show me the bus stops i see on google maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The website of the local transit operator TIB](https://www.tib.org/) has a route planner with fare calculation available. I plugged in a request for a trip from Palma to the *Coves del Drac* for tomorrow afternoon, and it gave me a few options, including a direct bus from the Intermodal center in Palma to the Mestral 2 stop in Portocristo, about 18 minutes' walk from the caves. According to this website, a ticket costs €5.40 if paid with a card or bought online, or €9.00 if bought with cash on board. Cost savings [are available](https://www.tib.org/es/billetes-y-tarifas/tarjeta-bancaria) if buying a ticket for more than one person at a time or if you use the *tarjeta intermodal*, [though this is only available](https://www.tib.org/es/billetes-y-tarifas/tarjeta-intermodal#general-conditions) to residents of Mallorca. You can plug in your own exact starting point and time of travel for personalized advice.

Comment: Not exact, but pretty close to the R2R report. Given the cost of getting to the Balearics in the first place, it's a noise-level deviation.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable source for local transport information is [Rome2Rio.com](https://www.rome2rio.com).

Clicking on the little right-pointing arrows will display the next screen, with more information; from that screen, click again on the right-pointing arrows for more information about the carrier, including schedule and times.

Comment: @Willeke The third Rome2Rio page in (following the little right arrows) does present the local schedule and identifies the carrier. (That third page doesn't display a different URL, so I can't link to it, and adding an image that contains text into the answer is inappropriate for indexing purposes.) Is R2R as a reference and source for further search so disfavored that I should not mention it?

Comment: it gives an estimate fare. How do I find the exact ones?

Comment: Contact the bus company directly and ask. The company's website is shown on the R2R page. There is likely to be contact information there.